# SQL statement, check if other rows have the same value

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, select, datatable

I have a SQL statement that imports my product inventory from a Access.MDB file. The select statement is below. (well a portion of it)

```
SELECT 
    Brand, DESCRIPTION AS Model, 
    SECONDDESCRIPTION AS Description, 
    PRODUCT AS [Product Code], TYPE AS Batch, INACTIVE, 
    CORE AS [Core Range], 
    IIF([CUSTORD] IS NULL, ROUND(ON_HAND), (IIF(TYPE = 'DISP',ROUND(ON_HAND),ROUND(ON_HAND)-CUSTORD))) AS SOH
```

You may notice that the select statement will minus any items that are on a customer order from the SOH values. for clarity below is the line that does just that.

```
IIF([CUSTORD] IS NULL, ROUND(ON_HAND), (IIF(TYPE = 'DISP',ROUND(ON_HAND),ROUND(ON_HAND)-CUSTORD))) AS SOH
```

The problem i have is, that 1 product code, can have multiple batches, and if an item only has a qty of 1 in each batch, and then the customer order column also contains a 1, this results in 1 - 1 = 0.

However the customer orders column is really indicating that only 1 of the product codes in on a customer order, not that specific batch.

Is there a way to check if that product code has already been "Selected" and has a Customer Order Qty against it and if it does then ignore the customer order qty against this next batch in the table?

To help explain it a little here is a rough idea of the table that would be imported.

| Product | Batch_Number | ON_HAND | CUSTORD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apples | 123456 | 5 | 1 |
| Apples | 234567 | 1 | 1 |
| Apples | 587554 | 1 | 1 |
| Bananas | 1548777 | 1 | 0 |

so in the table above with my existing select statement, my results would be

Apples 4 in batch 123456

Bananas 1 in batch 1548777

As the next two lines of apples would actually end up with a value of 0 in batches 234567 and 587554

my program is set to then only return to the user values of items they can sell with a SOH qty > 0

so i need the final datatable in my program to look like this:

| Product | Batch_Number | ON_HAND | CUSTORD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apples | 123456 | 5 | 1 |
| Apples | 234567 | 1 | 0 |
| Apples | 587554 | 1 | 0 |
| Bananas | 1548777 | 1 | 0 |

In my table Batch Number is the unique identifier and does not occur twice in the table.

Im working in VB.NET so if it could not be done in the SQL select statement i could be open to the idea of adjusting the values in the dataset datatable, however that would probably be made harder by the fact that the SQL Select statement i'm using never actually imports the CUSTORD column of data into my datatable. As i was trying to handle the SOH values directly at the select statement level.

Hope i have not confused anyone, and explained it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what your initial code has to do with the question.  But let me assume that you have a table in the format shown in the question and you want to set `on_hand` to `0` for all but the first row for each product.  You can use:

```
select product, batch_number, custord,
       iif( t.batch_number = (select top 1 t2.batch_number
                              from t as t2
                              where t2.product = t.product
                              order by t2.on_hand desc, t2.batch_number
                             ),
            t.on_hand, 0
          ) as adjusted_on_hand
from t
order by product, on_hand desc, batch_number
```

Comment: Not `on_hand` set to `0` rather the first row of `CUSTORD` would keep its value, all remaining rows of `CUSTORD` would be set to zero where the `Productcode` is the same. I should be able to interpret your example tho and apply it to my scenario when I'm back at my desk.

Comment: i managed to get it to work, with this: 


`SELECT t.product, t.batch, t.custord, t.on_hand,

iif(t.batch = (SELECT top 1 t2.batch FROM INVXLS as t2 

where t2.product = t.product),t.on_hand, t.on_hand - t.custord) AS newproduct 

FROM INVXLS as t 
ORDER BY t.product desc`